# Vuejs search doesn't refresh list

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am building an app and part of that app is to search for creators according to artistName.  When the listing page loads first time it shows the list of all the creators.
But there is an input field when the list can be filtered according to artist name and although I can see that it returns the correct search result, the page doesn't refresh and the full list is still showing.
And in the javascript console i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
```

whereas the console.log in the method gives me the correct value.

Here it the input field

```html
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search by artistName"
  v-model="artistName"
/>
<button
  @click="searchArtistName"
>
  Search
</button>
```

And this is the function that filters the results

```js
 data() {
   return {
     creators: [],
     currentCreator: null,
     currentIndex: -1,
     artistName: "",
     errors: [],
   };
 },
 methods: {
   searchArtistName() {
     DataService.findByArtistName(this.artistName)
       .then((response) => {
         this.creators = response.data;
         console.log(this.creators);
       })
       .catch((e) => {
         console.log(e);
       });
   },
 },
```

And this is what draws the list

```js
<ul>
  <li
    :class="{ active: index == currentIndex }"
    v-for="(item, index) in creators"
    :key="index"
    @click="setActiveCreator(item, index)"
  >
    id: {{ item.id }}, {{ item.artistName }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working?

Comment: what error you encounter in console?

Comment: it's obvious that you don't have item.id in your object, at least you can show console.log of this.creators in response?

Comment: No in the console.log i can see the object and it has the correct id

Comment: can you give an screenshot of log

Comment: Evaluation of objects logged with `console.log` happens when you open the object in your console, which may mean it has already changed. Pause execution after the console.log with `debugger` and evaluate it then to see what is actually inside of it. If there is anything else changing `this.creators` please include it as well.

Comment: I did some debugging and it appears lets say if the original list had 3 objects and filtered result only had 1, it acts as though it is still looping over 3 objects and as the other 2 objects are null, this is when the error is thrown

Comment: @amir exactly what i wrote in answer, so, look at you DataService and prevent null object, or try this in your li text,    id: {{ item ? item.id  : '' }}, {{ item ? item.artistName : '' }} to null free in rendering.

Comment: Why your DataService put null in array, not a good practice

Comment: No that's not the issue data service returns the correct items and they all have ids, because they are coming from the db.

Comment: Ok, good, try snippet in answer, and also you are modify objects in DataService ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I found the answer. The problem was with the data format from the api. It was returning an object, not an array hence it could not be assigned to creators array correctly.
I changed it into an Iterable object and now the list filters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your response, and items

You have an item with value of null (like `creator100: null`),

And when you iterate through creators you get and item = null and when trying to access item.id you get this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')`

use  `id: {{ item ? item.id : index }}, {{ item ? item.artistName : '' }}` to null free in rendering and know when you get null value.

You can try null.id in Browser console to achieve a error like that.

if you wanna look deeper, expand error log in console, and attach an screenshot to question.